# Package Passes R CMD check in Linux, Windows Binary Fails

Tags: r

I submitted version 0.1-8 of a robust package I created to CRAN.  R CMD Check passed on my computer runnning 64 bit Ubuntu and Rstudio. The Linux and Mac binaries are passing on CRAN.  The windows binaries are failing on CRAN.  The only difference between version 0.1-7 and 0.1-8 is I changed the namespace to adhere to the new version of R and I improved the documentation.  None of the code has been changed.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustreg/index.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_robustreg.html

Can anyone help me with the below error message?

```
* using log directory 'd:/Rcompile/CRANpkg/local/3.2/robustreg.Rcheck'
* using R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ISO8859-1
* checking for file 'robustreg/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* this is package 'robustreg' version '0.1-8'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking whether package 'robustreg' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'd:/Rcompile/CRANpkg/local/3.2/robustreg.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
* DONE
The installation logfile:
* installing *source* package 'robustreg' ...
** package 'robustreg' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/temp/RtmpI9QsDz/R.INSTALL4b704d36335d/robustreg/src-i386'
g++  -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.2.1/include"            -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.2/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -mtune=core2            -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.2.1/include"            -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.2/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -mtune=core2            -c fit.cpp -o fit.o
g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o robustreg.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o fit.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LD:/RCompile/recent/R-3.2.1/bin/i386 -lR
fit.o:fit.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper<false>::apply<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Col<double> >(arma::Mat<arma::Mat<double>::elem_type>&, arma::Glue<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Col<double>, arma::glue_times> const&)]+0x262): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
fit.o:fit.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper<false>::apply<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Col<double> >(arma::Mat<arma::Mat<double>::elem_type>&, arma::Glue<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Col<double>, arma::glue_times> const&)]+0x4a2): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
fit.o:fit.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper<false>::apply<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Col<double> >(arma::Mat<arma::Mat<double>::elem_type>&, arma::Glue<arma::Mat<double>, arma::Col<double>, arma::glue_times> const&)]+0xb4c): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/temp/RtmpI9QsDz/R.INSTALL4b704d36335d/robustreg/src-i386'
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/temp/RtmpI9QsDz/R.INSTALL4b704d36335d/robustreg/src-i386'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/temp/RtmpI9QsDz/R.INSTALL4b704d36335d/robustreg/src-i386'
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'robustreg'
* removing 'd:/Rcompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.2/robustreg'
* restoring previous 'd:/Rcompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.2/robustreg'
```

Comment: I'd seriously consider posting this to R-package-devel:  https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel (tons of super-helpful folks there as well as here)

Comment: I did on Friday.  It wasn't mod approved.

Comment: Have you sent it to http://win-builder.r-project.org/?  I had the same issue with my package not running on Windows and win-builder helped me fix it.

Comment: Post again.  There are moderators who have to flag first-time-posters; after that you're good.   That list is a better place than SO.

Comment: Also, as this appears to be a Rcpp/RcppArmadillo question, consider our list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its automatically-created GitHub mirror and the src/ directory there in](https://github.com/cran/robustreg/tree/master/src), you do not have a file `src/Makevars.win`.   And you now have a linking error with LAPACK routines.

Simply add a file such as [this one added when you use `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/skeleton/Makevars.win) containing just

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

and you should be all set:

I am surprised this worked previously. You mostly got lucky--our documentation clearly says you need it.

Comment: That is exactly it.  Fixed and tested on win-builder.

Comment: Glad to hear. In which case you may want to show thanks by 'accepting' (click on tick mark) and/or upvoting (click on arrow up).